# Запрашивать данные из Activity или из Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

В приложении есть база данных SQLite. Используется TabLayout, у вкладок соответственно свои фрагменты. Правильно будет подгружать данные при открытии каждой отдельной вкладки TabLayout (то есть из фрагментов), либо же делать это в Activity?

И если вообще речь идет не о TabLayout а просто о приложениях где используются Activity и Fragment, где выполнять подобные "операции"? Кто-то пишет прямо во фрагментах, но иногда встречаю где затратные операции лежат в Activity, а во фрагменты просто передают данные для вывода. Подскажите пожалуйста, как наиболее правильно и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragment по замыслу его создателей вмещает в себя описание куска интерфейса и его логики. Так что с их точки зрения вы должны получать данные во фрагменте, а не в активити. Активити выступает в роли глобального контроллера, но если вы будете пихать в нее всю логику она станет ужасающим монстром даже на простом проекте.

По поводу "просто передавать данные из активити во фрагмент для отображения" - такой подход уместен, но далеко не всегда.

Приведу пример: у вас есть список пользователей какого-либо сервиса. Вы отображаете его в одном фрагменте. У вас уже загружены полные данные по каждому из пользователей, но отображаются сейчас только никнейм и аватар. Когда вы кликаете по пункту списка - появляется новый фрагмент с подробными данными о выбранном юзере(настоящее имя, последний вход и т.п.). Если для отображения списка вы загрузили сразу подробные данные о пользователях, то данные о выбранном пользователе можно сразу передать в фрагмент.

Противоположная ситуация: есть список бесед, для каждой из которых вы загружаете последнее сообщение в этой беседе, чтобы его отобразить в списке. При переходе внутрь беседы вы не можете передавать данные туда, фрагмент с беседой должен сам из запросить из контент провайдера. Если вы сначала запросите данные, и только получив их попробуете открыть фрагмент - получите очень неотзывчивый интерфейс, который еще и допускает кучу всякого лишнего, например можно кликнуть по беседе, не дождаться ее открытия и кликнуть по другой. И это придется обрабатывать

Подытожу: Если вам нужно открыть фрагмент для отображения данных, которые уже есть в текущем состоянии - можете просто передать данные, но осторожно. Лучше всегда обращаться к контент провайдеру из того места, где эти данные должны быть отображены. К этому же нас подталкивают реактивные подходы к реализации интерфейсов. Если вы работаете с сетью - кэшируйте запросы, если с локальной бд - проблем быть не должно